# How can i get jwt refreshtoken in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, redux-saga

i'm using jwt token

Assume that accesstoken and refreshtoken are already saved when logging in.

getPostAPI is an API that imports post data and refreshAPI is a reissue of acesstoken.

Before the accesstoken expires, if i make a getPostAPI request, it responds well, but when the accesstoken expires, a 403 error occurs. At this time, when err is detected in catch (err) of getPost function, refreshAPI is executed through REFRESH_REQUEST, and when accesstoken is issued, it is saved in AsyncStorage, and then GETPOST_REQUEST is executed to execute getPostAPI to get a good response.

But I'm not sure if the method I used is the right way.

am i doing right way?

this is my code

```
    function getPostAPI(data) {
      return axiosInstace.post('/kakao/getpost', data);
    }

    function* getPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(getPostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: GETPOST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        yield put({
          type: REFRESH_REQUEST,
        });
        yield put({
          type: GETPOST_REQUEST,
          data: action.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function refreshAPI() {
      return axiosInstace.post('/kakao/refresh');
    }

    function* refresh() {
      try {
        const result = yield call(refreshAPI);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('accesstoken', `${result.data.accessToken}`, () => {});
        yield put({
          type: REFRESH_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        yield put({
          type: REFRESH_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function* getPost(action) {
  try {
    const result = yield call(getPostAPI, action.data);
    yield put({
      type: GETPOST_SUCCESS,
      data: result.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({
      type: REFRESH_REQUEST,
    });
    yield put({
      type: GETPOST_REQUEST,
      data: action.data,
    });
  }
}
```

call refresh function instead of `REFRESH_REQUEST` action

and call getPost function on `REFRESH_SUCCESS` action

```
function* getPost(action) {
  try {
    const result = yield call(getPostAPI, action.data);
    yield put({
      type: GETPOST_SUCCESS,
      data: result.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    yield refresh();
    yield put({
      type: GETPOST_REQUEST,
      data: action.data,
    });
  }
}

function* refresh() {
  try {
    const result = yield call(refreshAPI);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('accesstoken', `${result.data.accessToken}`, () => {});
    yield put({
      type: REFRESH_SUCCESS,
      data: result.data,
    });

    yield getPost(data);
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({
      type: REFRESH_FAILURE,
      error: err.response.data,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but this error occure cannot read property 'data' of undefined The above error occurred in task getPost

Comment: You are using result.data without checking result exist